# SASS/COMPASS @import

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I installed SASS + COMPASS + COMPASS-recipes but whenever i type @import "recipes"
it says: *"error main.scss (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: recipes."
Load path: C:/wamp/www/SASS/scss)*

css:

```
    @import "recipes";
body {
background-color: black;
}
```

config.rb:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require "compass-recipes"
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command    line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = :expanded
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors.    Uncomment:
line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

Comment: did you check whether there s a file named 'recipes' exist?

Comment: i did and it doesn't in that directory but thing is on the website itself it says this is how it's supposed to work

Comment: @Sam Compass extensions have their files live within a gem, so there won't be any files to check for on the file system.

Comment: it's not a duplicate as everything does work apart from the mixins and that other post didn't get his watch to run or w.e